# How to have a single delivery charge with Paypal?

Tags: paypal

I am working on a page and adding "Add to cart" buttons. Example:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="---------"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="xxxxxxx"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="A11"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="35.00"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="products"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="20.000"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="5.00"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-ShopCartBF:btn_cart_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest"/>
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
</form>
```

I would like to adjust it so that I have one fixed delivery charge ... rather than repeating it for each item.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the button already behaves as you desire.  It does not repeat the 5 GBP charge for each item.

Comment: Hi. I just tried my temporary page and added to products into the cart and the shipping is doubled up.

Comment: Do you have multiple buttons? In that case, shipping should not be part of the button.  Remove shipping and create a profile by logging into the receiving PayPal account and going to Profile -> My Selling Tools -> Shipping Calculations

Comment: Yes, the webpage has multiple buttons. I will look into what you said, thanks. As a side, I notice:

<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">

It has two target attributes. I guess this is wrong? It is the example code from the paypal website.

Comment: You can remove the _top one, it is a minor bug